# ¿Cómo definir alcances en interfaces de typescript?

Tags: typescript

Teniendo:

```
interface IY {
    hacerPublico : (p:any)=>void;
    hacerPrivado : (p:any)=>void;
}
class A implements IY { //--ERROR-- de typescript ts2420 
    constructor() {}
    public hacerPublico: (p: any) => void;
    private hacerPrivado: (p: any) => void;    
}
```

Partiendo de que una interfaz es una definición (o reglas) a seguir en la sección que la implemente.

En este caso que la interfaz `IY` se implementa en la clase `A` ¿cómo puedo definir que el método `hacerPrivado()` sea privado desde la interfaz y que typescript no genere error?

Si no estoy mal en otros lenguajes fuertemente tipados es permitido asignar alcances a las propiedades de las interfaces.

Algo así:

```
//No permitido en typescript
interface IY { 
    public hacerPublico : (param)=>void; 
    private hacerPrivado : (param)=>void;
}
```

Comment: Una interfaz es un contrato público que una clase debe implementar de tal manera que los clientes de la interfaz puedan saber qué métodos están disponibles en los objetos que las implementan. No tendría sentido agregar métodos privados en la interfaz si los clientes no sabrán de su existencia. En los lenguajes como Java, los métodos privados solo son accesibles en la misma interfaz, no son obligados a implementarse en las clases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las interfaces obligan a la implementación de sus métodos y propiedades en las clases que las implementan. Existe una confusión habitual que es pensar que el objetivo de la interfaz es ese, cuando no lo es. El objetivo de la interfaz es poder manipular objetos de clases distintas como si fueran lo mismo, a través de sus métodos y propiedades comunes.

No es un contrato por nada, es un contrato con un objetivo. Por eso no tiene sentido declarar un método como privado en un interfaz.

Luego los elementos privados, son accesibles dentro de su contexto (clase o interfaz), no son accesibles por otras clases que extienden o implementan de él. Si no de privados no tendrían mucho

A mí me parece que tu buscas otra cosa, que es obligar a una clase a tener una forma determinada, para esto puedes usar clases y funciones abstractas que obligan a la clase derivada a implementar tales funciones. Además debes hacer uso de `protected` en lugar de privado. Un `protected` solo se puede llamar por clases derivadas, pero no fuera de ella.

Ejemplo:

```
abstract class IY {
    public abstract hacerPublico(p:any) : void;
    protected abstract hacerPrivado(p:any) : void;
}
class A extends IY {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public override hacerPublico = function(p:any) :void {
        return;
    }
    protected override hacerPrivado = function(p:any) :void {
        return;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Gracias, @Yussef siendo sincero quería evitarme la herencia, porque la pregunta surgió de algunas situaciones como: que no deseo que las instancias de las clases que tengan el método `hacerPrivado()` se les permita el acceso, o que potencialmente podría tener varias interfaces a implementar en varias clases, la herencia me permitiría heredar (“implementar”) solo de una (la clase padre), pero también analizo que se empieza a generar un desorden y acercándome a terrenos peligrosos como simular una herencia múltiple.

Comment: @MagnerLesmes debe ser el autor de la respuesta quien edite su código, ya que la edición hace un cambio al sentido del mismo. En este caso, en lugar de editarlo por tu cuenta, debes avisarle al autor que la modifique.

Comment: @MagnerLesmes Es difícil entender la situación y seguro que también debe ser difícil para ti explicarla. El punto central, es que no tiene mucho sentido tener una interface con métodos privados, porque la razón de ser de la interface es poder acceder a elementos comunes sin que importe el tipo de clase. Yo creo que tu solución va por donde tú dices, tener múltiples interfaces que en general los frameworks ocupan esa estrategia para lograr ser lo suficientemente genericos.

Comment: @Yussef, pensé en varios apaños pero no son convenientes, realmente es mejor tratar de acoplar el código a la herencia y manejarlo así, gracias.

Comment: @Yussef, @padaleiana me indica que debo solicitarte la edición de la respuesta pero no se como solicitarla, el caso es de eliminar la asignacion de `hacerPublico()`, `hacerPrivado()` como propiedades de tipo `function` ya que en si son métodos no requieren ser asignados con valores `function`, es verboso.